# Subsonic - Simple Query

Tags: subsonic

I have a table has 2 columns

Val1 int

Val2 int

My query very simple.

I want to get collection of record have condition (val1=Val2) ,

equivalent to (Select * from table where Val1=Val2)

I try

IDataReader rdr = new Query("Table").WHERE("Val1=Val2").ExecuteReader();
        tableColl.LoadAndCloseReader(rdr);
        rdr.Close();

and

```
  ..WHERE (" 'Val1=Val2' ")
  ..WHERE (Table.Columns.Val1,IsEqualTo,Table.Columns.Val2) //This not reguler I know
  ..WHERE ("Val"+'='+"Val2") 
  .....
```

any help be more apricated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you'll need to do this as an inline query as far as I know:

```
TableCollection tableCollection = new InlineQuery()  
  .ExecuteAsCollection<TableCollection>(
    "SELECT * FROM " + Table.Schema.TableName " WHERE " + Table.Columns.Val1 + " = " + Table.Columns.Val2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.

Sorry for missing information. I am using Versiyon 2.0.3.
I Think DB.Select()... not supported in 2.0.3 versiyon.

Comment: No problem, I realised it wouldn't work the way I first suggested anyway. The InlineQuery should exist in 2.0.3 and work

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
Unfortunately InlineQuery() not suported In 2.0.3..
It seems I must  go to upgrade 2.1 version.

Comment: I'd recommend skipping 2.1 and compiling the source for 2.2 instead there's a a bunch of bugfixes in it.

http://blog.wekeroad.com/subsonic/subsonic-22-released/

Comment: In fact you can get the binaries here http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject/downloads/list

Answer (score 0):

was in same situation recently and came up with this:

```
TableCollection tablecollection = new TableCollection;
Comparison comp = Comparison.Equals;
tablecollection.Where(Table.Columns.Val1, comp, Table.Columns.Val2);
tablecollection.Load();
```

i found this better because i don't like inline queries. and it gives
more flexibility if you wish to allow for adhoc querying in you app.

Comment: Hi
Thanks to your answer.

But I tried it in ver 2.0.3 it s not working that I expected.
That suppsose  3. param like parameter. (Like 
tablecollection.Where(Table.Columns.Val1, comp, 5);

and generate sql like below
/* GetSelectSql(Table1) */ SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT  [dbo].[Table1].[ID], [dbo].[Table1].[Val1], [dbo].[Table1].[Val2]
  FROM [dbo].[Table1] WHERE [Table1].[Val1] = @Val20 ORDER BY [ID] ASC;

are you tired in 2.0.3 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CreateDynamicControls()
{


    panGvHolder.Controls.Clear();

    Query qry = Northwind.Product.CreateQuery();
    qry.Columns.AddRange(Northwind.Product.Schema.Columns);
    qry.WHERE("UnitPrice > 15").AND("UnitsInStock < 20 ");
    //WHERE("UnitPrice > 15").AND("UnitsInStock < 30 ");



    using (IDataReader rdr = qry.ExecuteReader())
    {
        Response.Write("<table>");
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Response.Write("<tr>");
            for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                Response.Write("<td>");
                Response.Write(rdr[i].ToString() + " ");
                Response.Write("<td>");
            } //eof for 
            Response.Write("</br>");
            Response.Write("</tr>");
        }
        Response.Write("<table>");
    }
} //eof method
```